# Atualizar Tabela com filtro usando jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, autocompletar

Bom dia estou procurando soluções para uma demanda, mas só encontrei em `php`. 
Sou novo em `Jquery`, `Ajax`... Estou querendo colocar o filtro da minha tabela para ser dinâmico na medida que o usuário for digitando vai aparecendo os dados, pesquisei uma `function` chamada `autocomplete`, mas não consegui implementar.

Minha Tabela.

```
 <table cellpadding="1" border="0" id="minhaTabela" class="table table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
   <thead class="fixedHeader">
     <tr bgcolor="${cortop}">
       <th width="20">&nbsp;</th>
       <th width="70">Prontu&aacute;rio</th>
       <th width="269"><b>pacientes</b></th>
       <th width="181"><b>Plano</b></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <c:forEach var="item" items="${pacientes}">
     <tr bgcolor="#F4F4F4" title="${item.titlo}">
       <td >
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio" onclick="selecionar('${item.cargo}', ${item.id}, '${item.plano}', ${item.idPlano}, '<%=request.getParameter("tipo")%>')" ondblclick="selecionar2('${item.cargo}', ${item.id}, '${item.plano}', ${item.idPlano}, '<%=request.getParameter("tipo")%>')" />
       </td>
       <td>${item.id}</td>
       <td nowrap="nowrap">${item.nome}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td nowrap="nowrap">${item.plano}</td>
     </tr>
   </c:forEach></table>
```

Através deste filtro eu estou puxando os dados do BD

```
<label  id="lbl" style="background: ${cortop}; color: ${corletra}" class="label label-info" >Nome:</label>
<input name="jtpaciente" type="text" class="form-control" id="jtpaciente"  value="<%=request.getAttribute("paci")%>" size="74" />
```

Quando o usuário digita e aperta enter então é feito um submit da pagina trazendo só o nome filtrado.Teria uma solução de adicionar esse `jquery` ou `ajax` nesta `table em jsp` ??

Comment: Já tentou com o plugin jQuery Datatables ?
https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: já sim, e funcionou normalmente, mas esse plugin faz tudo automatico inclusive adiciona um Campo já chamado Pesquisar acima da tabela.... mas neste meu caso eu gostaria de adicionar no input jtpaciente .

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei essa solução    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                                            var $rows = $('#minhaTabela tr');
                                            $('#jtpaciente').keyup(function() {

                                                var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
                                                    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
                                                    text;

                                                $rows.show().filter(function() {
                                                    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                                                    return !reg.test(text);
                                                }).hide();
                                            });

                                        </script>
```